# Wordpress ACF plugin: trouble getting field when saving post

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using ACF; I am making a plugin that hooks into WP on 'draft_to_publish' and on 'pending_to_publish' this part works fine. But when I try to get the ACF generated fields they return as blank, as if the fields generated by ACF haven't been set yet.

Short version of my plugin looks like this:

```
function scheduelMailChimp( $post ) {
    // get post data and preb it for mail
    $post_ID        = get_the_ID();
    $content_post   = get_post( $post_ID );
    $content        = $content_post->post_content;
    $postTitle      = get_the_title( $post_ID );

    //log debuginfo til debug.log
    log_me( 
        array( 
               'get field date' => get_field($field_name, $post_id, $format_value)
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'draft_to_publish', 'scheduelMailChimp', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'pending_to_publish', 'scheduelMailChimp', 10, 1 );
```

The above code outputs empty. If I try to output something that is generated by WP and not ACF everything works like a charm.

all and any bright ideas are more then welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In case other people are looking for the same answer: After diving into a ton of Google searches, it seems that ACF haven't saved the data at the time draft_to_publish is fired. So I tried using the 'save_post' and it worked like a charm.